# How to solve double quote problem when bulk inserting CSV in SQL Server?

Tags: python, sql-server, bulkinsert

When inserting a `.csv` file into my database, I'm running into a problem with double quotes.

[sample data]

[image]

There is no problem when I use pandas in python.

When doing bulk insert in SQL Server, no data is inserted.

This is my bulk insert code:

```
BULK INSERT TEMP.dbo.temp_table
FROM '/Users/Documents/test.csv'
WITH
    ( 
        CODEPAGE = 'RAW',
        DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
        FIRSTROW = 2,
        FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0A',
        FORMAT = 'CSV',
        TABLOCK
    );
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Is there a reason to use hexadecimal notation `0x0A` instead of `\n`? Could you also mention the SQL Server version. Is the Data(each cell) enclosed within double quotes "  in csv file ?

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar, Because of 'ANSI'. And each cell enclosed within ,(comma). SQL Server version is 2017. When i used type \n, the data is pushed in.

Comment: Are the double-quotes escaped (doubled up `""`)? Also is it an ANSI file, UTF-8 or UTF-16? What is the row terminator?

Comment: [Bulk insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) has supported RFC 4180 compliant CSV files since SQL Server 2017, so if you're unable to import a .csv file it's probably not encoded correctly.

Comment: @Charlieface, well it is 'utf-8'. When I tried several methods, I thought it was the best.

Comment: I have a feeling `0x0A` doesn't work in the way you intend. Either way, what is the actual row terminator?

Comment: @Charlieface, Well actual row terminator is '\n'. But, the row is pushed aside.

Comment: So use `\n` instead. And are the quotes doubled-up as they should be: `"` becomes `""`

Comment: @Charlieface Yes, quotes doubled-up! When [col1] has a value of 1002, split the col3 due to ,(comma).

Comment: I'm assuming that `Saf A, B` is actually quoted in the file also, like so `"Saf A, B"`?

Comment: @Charlieface, Well, When I checking in text editor....It is quoted in the file.

Comment: Try `CODEPAGE='65001'` maybe

Comment: @Charlieface Sorry about that, It makes error.